# ExtJS call controller method inside Ext.util.Observable.observe

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have my 4.2.1 ExtJS application listen to every Ajax request (`Ext.data.Connection`) so I can do custom error handling and other stuff.

Im doing that inside my `Main Controller`

```
Ext.define('App.controller.Main', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


        init: function (application) {

            var me = this;

            this.control({
                '[xtype=login] button#btnLogin': {
                    click: me.onLogin
                },
            });

            Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
                requestcomplete: function (conn, response, options) {
                    // Do stuff on success
                },
                requestexception: me.handleRequestException // Do stuff on failure
            });

        },
        handleRequestException: function (conn, response, options) {

            var me = this;

            if (response.status == 401) {

                // here i need to fire the logoutApplication method

                // have tried: me.fireEvent('logoutApplication');  but fireEvent is undefined because "me" scope is data.Connection
                // it doesnt know about the controller.

            }


        },
        logoutApplication: function () {
            var me = this;

            // do somestuff here!!

        }
```

Inside the `handleRequestException` function Im trying to do `me.fireEvent(...)` but `fireEvent` is `undefined` because the `scope` of the function is `data.Connection`.

I **don't** want to use:

```
var mainController = App.app.getController('App.controller.Main');
```

Because when calling that the `init` is fired and I get issues with event firing twice.

Im new in `ExtJS` so Im sure there is a better way to do this. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `scope` to the listeners configuration:

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
     requestcomplete: function (conn, response, options) {
         // Do stuff on success
     },
     requestexception: me.handleRequestException, // Do stuff on failure
     scope: me // add the scope here
});
```

Now you listeners get executed with that scope instead of the caller scope.

Comment: I create a extjs question that is breaking my head. Do you think you can check it please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978039/extjs-4-2-datepicker-multiselect-catch-event-in-controller