# ExtJS 4.2 DatePicker Multiselect catch event in controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am creating a custom date-picker in **ExtJS 4.2** using the *MVC* architecture.  The idea is that the component allows a user to input / select multiple dates at a time however I am having a few issues:

- My `selectedDates` variable is an object and I don't how how to make it return the list of dates.
- When you open a new window the picker remembers the previously selected dates from the last time that the window was open.  I thought that when you `close` a window in `Ext`, the components are **destroyed**?

There is a little too much code to paste into my post but I've created a [**fiddle here**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/84j).  I placed a button where on click, I want to get the selected dates - could someone please take a look?

Comment: Take a look at this one, may give you some ideas: https://github.com/nohuhu/Ext.ux.form.field.MultiDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `define` a class in Ext the properties you specify in the configuration exist in the prototype chain, **not** the object instance itself.  Unless a new object is assigned to `selectedDates` when the component's constructor is called then you are modifying a the **same** reference to a **single** object.  When you `close` a window the object **is** destroyed but the prototype / class-definition still exists.

If you want to use composite types as *"default"* values then you should resolve these in the object's `constructor` method.  For example:

```js
Ext.define('MyClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    // ...
    selectedDates: null,

    constructor: function(args){
        args = args || {};
        Ext.applyIf(args, {
            selectedDates: {}
        });
        this.callParent([args]);
    }
});
```

---

Getting your `selectedDates` is the easy part, it's just a case of iterating over your object and adding the values to an array - further to that the only thing you are missing is an `itemId` on your picker component so that you can easily obtain a reference to it, for example:

```js
Ext.define('HighlightableDatePicker', {

    // ...

    getSelectedDates: function(){
        var dates = [];
        Ext.iterate(this.selectedDates, function(key, val){
            dates.push(val);
        });
        dates.sort();
        return dates;
    }
});
```

```js
// Ext.Window items config...
{
    xtype: 'highlightdate',
    itemId: 'datePicker'
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Get Selected Dates',
    handler: function(){
        var picker = this.up('window').down('#datePicker');
        console.log( picker.getSelectedDates() );
    }
}
```

[**» updated fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/84j)

*Note:* there's no ***MVC*** in your fiddle but the same principle applies - you already have a `handleSelectionChanged` method where you could fire a custom event, for example:

```js
handleSelectionChanged: function(cmp, date){
    // after existing logic ...
    this.fireEvent('dateselection', this.getSelectedDates());
}
```

Now that the picker component has an `itemId`, your controller will be able to listen for the event.

Comment: I don't have words to thank your support and time spent for such complete explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: why not just set selectedDates: {} inside initComponent? Why using constructor?

Comment: @VAAA you could use either if it works for you - I have a tendency to suggest `constructor` because ***a)*** it exists on all classes *(not just components)* and ***b)*** it's called before anything is rendered.  If for example you were passing pre-selected dates to the picker to reflect the current state of whatever it is that it's representing, then you'd want to ensure this is the case otherwise you may have a scenario where the data doesn't get rendered - or the component is executing the render process twice unnecessarily.