# select multiple dates by dragging over datepicker dates

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs datepicker.
I want to select multiple dates of datepicker by dragging over them.

For that I tried to make calendar dates draggable. I took the reference from here https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/drag_drop.html and wrote below mentioned code.

```
var calendarDate = Ext.get('DatePickerSchedule').select('td');
        Ext.each(calendarDate.elements, function(el) {
            var dd = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DD', el, 'datesDDGroup', {
                isTarget: true
            });
            //Apply the overrides object to the newly created instance of DD
            Ext.apply(dd, window.overrides);
        });
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Previously Answered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978039/extjs-4-2-datepicker-multiselect-catch-event-in-controller). There's a fiddle provided that demonstrates how to implement multi-select on a date picker. It doesn't use dragging but it may be a suitable solution for your needs.

EDIT:

So this question really got me interested in how you might go about solving this. So I've had a play around and created custom date picker that extends the ExtJS datepicker but provides drag support for multiple selections using the mouse listeners I had suggested in my comment.

The fiddle can be found here [DraggableDatePicker](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/oi1)

One improvement you may want to make is to make the component aware of rows and the values within rows, so that when you mouse over a new row all dates on that row (prior to the one currently with the mouseover) are selected. My solution only cares about individual cells that are dragged over.

Comment: I need to select dates by dragging over them not by clicking individual dates. Off course purpose is met of selecting multiple dates but this is not functional need. Functionally it should select dates by dragging over them.

Comment: OK I see.

Without having looked into the datepicker source code I feel like you may need to extend the class and add listeners for _mousedown_, _mouseover_ and _mouseup_ to get the functionality you need.

And when _mousemove_ events are fired after an initial _mousedown_ on an element you can set the corresponding element to selected.

Comment: thanks for your time you devoted on problem. your solution looks very nice